# No internet connection and connectivity between some devices on a network

Tags: networking, pfsense

My home network was running 100% fine before I left for holidays, now I'm having a few issues. Here is a basic network diagram that outlines the key features.

[image: basic network diagram]

The network is as follows: 
I have pfSense running on a small NUC with 4 ports. 1 is for the WAN and the other 3 are used internally (LAN 192.168.0.0/24, Home 192.168.1.0/24, Security Cameras 192.168.2.0/24). The LAN network houses a domain controller (AD, DNS, DHCP), a TrueNAS storage server, and a box running ProxMox. The Home network runs our TV, printers, Google Nest etc. The Security Camera network runs the security cameras.

Current issues: Truenas and ProxMox are unable to connect to the internet, ping pfSense, or ping any other device in the network. When Laptop 1 is connected to the LAN network, it is also unable to connect to the internet.

Some troubleshooting notes that I've found:

- When Laptop 1 is connected to the Home or Security Camera network, it is able to connect to the internet, however, it is unable to ping Truenas or ProxMox. When connected to the LAN network, it is unable to ping pfSense, but can ping Truenas and ProxMox.
- The Domain controller is able to ping everything on any network
- The VM's running on Truenas and ProxMox are able to connect to the internet and any other device in the network. Their hosts are unable to though.

The pfSense firewall has rules in place to allow communication between all 3 networks. It also allows FTP to Truenas and port 80/443 to the BigBlueButton VM running on Truenas. Vlans are not in use.

I am fairly sure this is not a pfSense issue as some devices on the LAN network (domain controller and the 2 VMs) have unrestricted access. However, I am struggling to figure out what could possibly be the problem.

This is not a DNS issue as all devices (wheather they can access the internet or not) are able to lookup DNS through the domain contoller. Typing a FQDN vs an IP does not make any difference in results.

Please let me know what logs/information/screenshots you'd like to assist.

Comment: A schema of your network will help, to be edited into your post.

Comment: There's a hyperlink on the second line of text.

Comment: Sounds like the network switch at 192.168.0.9 is acting up. However, despite the abundance of information provided here that isn’t really any substantive network troubleshooting done. What is the IP address, subnet, dns, gateway configuration that the devices are receiving when they aren’t working.   If the switch is acting up it’s likely an ARP issue. Check the output of arp -a and see if the hosts you are trying to ping show up (after attempting ping) which indicates ARP is working. Confirm the MAC addresses seen via arp -a and make sure there isn’t some type of ARP flooding or spoofing.

Comment: Thansk for the tip. Turns out ARP was the issue. The MAC addresess stored on some machines were very different to the addresses stored on the pfSense ARP table.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this issue by simply deleting the ARP table on the pfSense router.